# Stream live from my own website

Tags: stream, video-streaming, live, rtmp, live-streaming

I want to stream live video from my website. This website will be basically for a TV Channel which hosts shows 24 hours. So, this video will stream live for 24 hours like some sports channel. So, If anyone have some idea of Streaming video wholeday from my own website, please tell me.

I have searched and found out solution for encoder as Teradek Vidiu and Software solution as DaCast and UStream.

But, I did not find DaCast or UStream useful for providing stream from my website for whole day. They are useful when I want to go for any event streaming. I Can also go for Developing my own RTMP Server, but i found that it will have security issues then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MonaServer](http://monaserver.ovh). I'm the co-author of this project, it is a media server that is well suited for real-time streaming as it implements RTMFP (no more security issues than other solutions). It is already used by TV channels. You can develop your flash client or ask us to build it.

You can try publishing with this sample : http://raspi.monaserver.ovh/MonaClients/VideoPublisher/

And reading with this one : http://raspi.monaserver.ovh/MonaClients/VideoPlayer/

And you can use Netgroup for P2P streaming if you have limited bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free nginx-rtmp module for NGINX fast web server, which supports recording, on-the-fly encoding, RTMP broadcasting, authorization and statistic page.
We used it in an online education project for video recording and it worked good.
https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki

According to our tests - works much better and faster then other opensource Red5 or crtmpd servers. Good opensource RTMP server alternative.